# Docker compose --wait not waiting for healthcheck

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Grafana with Loki compose file and I want to wait for Loki to be ready before proceeding with my script.

Loki provides a `/ready` endpoint that returns a non-200 when it isn't ready, so I'm trying to use it for the compose `healthcheck`.

However, not only is that curl not working, any health check I specify (even `exit 1`) is being ignored.

I have a few other services, but the gist of the compose file is the following:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

name: grafana

networks:
  grafana:

services:
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.4.0
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml
    volumes:
      - loki-data:/loki
    networks:
      - grafana
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -f http://127.0.0.1:3100
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 15

# a few more below...
```

In `healthcheck` I tried the following (to no avail):

- `test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://127.0.0.1:3100/ready"]`
- `test: exit 1` (just to confirm it's being ignored)

The commands I run to validate this config are:

- `docker compose down -f grafana.yaml down -v`
- `docker compose up -f grafana.yaml up --wait -d` (also tried without `-d`)

The `up` log even reports it being `healthy`:

```
✔ Network grafana_grafana         Created 0.0s 
✔ Volume "grafana_grafana-data"   Created 0.0s 
✔ Volume "grafana_loki-data"      Created 0.0s 
✔ Volume "grafana_prom-data"      Created 0.0s 
✔ Container grafana-promtail-1    Started 0.1s 
✔ Container grafana-grafana-1     Healthy 0.0s 
✔ Container grafana-prometheus-1  Healthy 0.0s 
✔ Container grafana-loki-1        Healthy 0.0s <--- here
```

Also worth noting that after running the `up` and having it report as healthy, making that `curl` on the host fails with 503 (before the container is actually ready).

As suggested in the comments, I tried adding `start_period: 20s` but it also didn't work.

Docker compose version: v2.21.0-desktop.1

Docker engine version: 24.0.6

Comment: Don't you need `start_period`? (also, make sure your docker runtime supports this as some of these features were added recently)

Comment: @istepaniuk Updated with the versions, and it also didn't work with `start_period`. I'm starting to believe it's a docker bug.